# How to find out if any method is written without having try catch block

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, code-standards

In a Visual Studio 2010 C# Project, how do I find out if any method is written without having a try-catch block?

Sometimes as a code reviewer, its hard to search function/methods which are not properly written according to code standards esp: without a try-catch block.

I know that the *Find* option in Visual Studio supports regular expressions. But what's the regular expression that could perform this job smartly?

Comment: How does having Try/catch help you find if a method is written? interested to see.

Comment: I believe the author is asking how to find methods which don't have try/catch blocks in them.

Comment: Of course, having a try/catch block in a method isn't always required or even helpful, so no upvote on the question from me.

Comment: Yes, Peter you got it. I actually edited the question and added more description. And why -1??

Comment: Peter: may be not helpful to you, but according to my job and task its important. :)

Comment: I didn't vote either way - I dont' think it's a good question, but it's not so bad as to deserve a -1. I think it will lead more to discussion of exception handling practice which is well covered elsewhere.

Comment: Regular expression to search for this? How would you determine using regex which code belongs to try-catch block and which doesn't?

Comment: @Mazhar Karimi, no. **Trying to ensure every method has a try-catch block is terrible practice**. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973642

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit (putting the direct answer first):** It would actually be easy to use [Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom.aspx), then enumerate the [types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes), and the [methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethods) of those types, then for each [method body](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody) examine the [ExceptionHandlingClauses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody.exceptionhandlingclauses).

**Commentary follows:**

Red Gate used to offer the [Exception Hunter](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/exception-hunter/) tool for tracking down possible exception issues. As mentioned on that page, it's been shown that the *specific* task you have requested (broad searches for any unhandled exception) does not lead to higher quality software even with assistance of automated analysis tools.

If I needed to find a list of all methods without a protected region, I could <strike>simply use one of my experimental assembly loaders (written with relative ease according to ECMA-335) and examine the metadata as described in ECMA-335, Partition II, §25.4.5 and §25.4.6</strike> (much easier to use the first part of this answer). If I needed to find a list of these methods for the purpose of adding a protected region to each of them to conform to a coding standard, I would report back that they need to find another developer to do that because I refuse to knowingly and intentionally degrade the quality of software I work on.

Comment: *I would report back that they need to find another developer to do that because I refuse to knowingly and intentionally degrade the quality of software I work on.* +1

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Visual Studio 2012 (the beta is a free download!), you can use the Search For Code Clones option.

Normally this will search your whole solution but you can scope it to a specific piece of code. You can easily use this to find all code where, for example, a disposable object is used. Then you can chek if a using statement is used everywhere.

This same mechanism can be used to check if a certain piece of code is used in a try/catch block.

Here is some MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfs/hh205279%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I **think** you could use [Roslyn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Roslyn) to process the code and find which methods have or don't have try/catch blocks by examining the expression tree.

I would not advise you to use Regex to do that. You'd have to write a quite complex script that would be a state machine based on when a method block starts and when it finishes, and then inspecting whether are try-catches in there.

Comment: that... I already know and mentioned in question, what would be the regular expression, that's a question. :)

Comment: @MazharKarimi, I guess you didn't understood my answer. I *do not* advise using Regex to do that. It would be quite complex, maybe more than 40 manhours -- which I don't have. I gave you an alternative, Roslyn. Hope it helps.